# Merging PDF with ITextSharp takes time

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I am using ITextSharp to merge PDFs.
My problem is when I merge huge PDFs, it takes a very long time to do it (many minutes). It appears that it takes all this time on the "document.close()".

Here is my code :

```
iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();

PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, msOutput);
copy.SetMergeFields();

doc.Open();
byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String("someString");

PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray);
copy.AddDocument(reader);

doc.Close(); // <== It takes time here !
byte[] form = msOutput.ToArray();
```

Is there anything I did wrong ?
How can I improve this merging time ?

Comment: What is 'reader' in your code?  Is it always long, or does it get longer (i.e. is it maybe a problem of disposing of your reader etc?

Comment: I've updated my code. it always take time on huge PDF (for example, I try to merge 3 pdf with 36 pages each)

Comment: 36 pages isn't really all that big.  Are they large file sizes?

Comment: Can you share the PDFs in question. It might be a matter of the forms inside.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really share it as it's for a confidential use. but the pdf contains a form with a lot of fields (acrofields).

Answer (score 0):

You are missing some Close() calls - this may help to bring your time down:

```
byte[] form
using (var msOutput = new MemoryStream())
{
    iTextSharp.text.Document doc = new iTextSharp.text.Document();
    byte[] byteArray = Convert.FromBase64String("someString");

    PdfCopy copy = new PdfCopy(doc, msOutput);

    copy.SetMergeFields();

    doc.Open();

    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(byteArray);

    copy.AddDocument(reader);

    reader.Close();
    copy.Close();

    doc.Close(); 

    form = msOutput.ToArray();
}
```

You should also be sure you are properly disposing of your stream after use.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give it a try. I actually use "using" for my MemoryStream

Comment: when I try to close either the reader or the copy or both, it throws an error "it is already closed".